# Do Python functions know how many outputs are requested?

Tags: python

In Python, do functions know how many outputs are requested? For instance, could I have a function that normally returns one output, but if two outputs are requested, it does an additional calculation and returns that too?

Or is this not the standard way to do it? In this case, it would be nice to avoid an extra function argument that says to provide a second input. But I'm interested in learning the standard way to do this.

Comment: No, functions have no idea; unpacking of a returned tuple happens after the function call. Usually you'd write two functions for this use case. You could call the single-return-value function from the two-return-value one so as not to duplicated code.

Comment: Only one `return` will ever be reached within a function; however, there is no type constraint on the return. So, for example, the same function could return `True` and, given different inputs/conditions, return `(True,'ABC')` - though this is generally not good design since one my not know what to expect when using the function

Comment: Could you give an example of when/why you need this? If it was for testing you could have an environment variable or a global variable that controls this!

Comment: Outputs aren't "requested". The function returns what it returns and the caller deals with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The real and easy answer is: No.

Python functions/methods does not know about how many outputs are requested, as unpacking of a returned tuple happens after the function call.

What's quite a best practice to do though is to use underscore (_) as a placeholder for unused args that are returned from functions when they're not needed, example:

```
def f():
    return 1, 2, 3

a, b, c = f()  # if you want to use all
a, _, _ = f()  # use only first element in the returned tuple, 'a'
_, b, _ = f()  # use only 'b'
```

For example, when using underscore (_) pylint will suppress any unused argument warnings.

Answer (score 5):

Python functions always return exactly 1 value.

In this case:

```
def myfunc():
    return
```

that value is None. In this case:

```
def myfunc():
    return 1, 2, 3
```

that value is the tuple (1, 2, 3).

So there is nothing for the function to know, really.

As for returning different outputs controlled by parameters, I'm always on the fence about that. It would depend on the actual use case. For a public API that is used by others, it is probably best to provide two separate functions with different return types, that call private code that does take the parameter.